# Custom UISlider doesn't go to end

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uislider

I have created a UISlider that has tick marks and snaps to each tick when the value is changed. The problem is that the slider doesn't naturally go to the ends and the left and right tick are visible outside of the circle. I have extended the UISlider class to go to the ends but the animation conflicts with moving the slider to the next tick and the circle ends up off the screen. How can I keep the snap to tick animation and have the circle in the slider go all the way to the end? Here is my code

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect
    {
        let unadjustedThumbrect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
        let thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide:CGFloat = unadjustedThumbrect.size.width / 2.0
        let minOffsetToAdd = -thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
        let maxOffsetToAdd = thumbOffsetToApplyOnEachSide
        let offsetForValue = minOffsetToAdd + (maxOffsetToAdd - minOffsetToAdd) * CGFloat(value / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue))
        var origin = unadjustedThumbrect.origin
        origin.x += offsetForValue
        return CGRect(origin: origin, size: unadjustedThumbrect.size)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var slider: CustomSlider!

let tickArray : [Float] = [Float(18),Float(20),Float(22),Float(24),Float(26),Float(28),Float(30)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.slider.value = tickArray[0]
        self.slider.minimumValue = tickArray[0]
        self.slider.maximumValue = tickArray[6]
        self.slider.isContinuous = false



        var tick : UIView
        for i in 0..<tickArray.count-1 {
            tick = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (self.slider.frame.size.width/6) * CGFloat(i), y: (slider.frame.size.height - 13) / 2, width: 2, height: 13))
            tick.backgroundColor = "8E8E93".hexColor
            slider.insertSubview(tick, belowSubview: slider)
        }

        tick = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.slider.frame.size.width-2, y: (slider.frame.size.height - 13) / 2, width: 2, height: 13))
        tick.backgroundColor = "8E8E93".hexColor
        slider.insertSubview(tick, belowSubview: slider)

    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {


            if sender.value > tickArray[5] {
                slider.value = tickArray[6]
            } else if sender.value > tickArray[4] {
                slider.value = tickArray[5]
            } else if sender.value > tickArray[3] {
                slider.value = tickArray[4]
            } else if sender.value > tickArray[2] {
                slider.value = tickArray[3]
            } else if sender.value > tickArray[1] {
                slider.value = tickArray[2]
            } else if sender.value >
                tickArray[0] {
                slider.value = tickArray[1]
            } else {
                slider.value = tickArray[0]
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide an image of exactly what the issue looks like?

Comment: I have attached one to my post. You can see the right tick to the right of the circle.

Comment: the image shows the initial problem of the slider not going all the way to the right

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by hiding the left and right ticks when the slider goes to the edges. This took away the need for the slider extension.